# In OWL, is it possible to query a class that does not have a property?

Tags: owl

In [OWL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language), is it possible to query a class that does not have a property?

Suppose I have an object property R and I want to retrieve all classes that do not have the property R. Also, suppose that I have already closed all classes with closures.

I was trying this:

suppose the propety in question is hasProperty, my query was this

```
hasProperty only Nothing
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean?  Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: it doesn't return those classes that doesn't has a relation along the property hasProperty

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "class that does not have a property"?

Semantically, a class is a set of individuals and a property is a set of pairs of individuals. Given these two sets, what do you mean by "class has / has not a property"?

Regarding your example query

```
hasProperty only Nothing
```

lets rewrite it a bit so that we can think about it in natural language. This gives better intuition about the meaning of this query.

First lets rename `hasProperty` to `follows` (or whatever English verb), then we have:

```
follows only Nothing
```

This is semantically equivalent to

```
follows only (not Thing)
```

which is semantically equivalent to

```
not (follows some Thing)
```

Now we have gotten rid of the `only` which is a confusing part of OWL and is better avoided. So now we can verbalize the query in English as:

```
those who do not follow anything
```

or

```
who does not follow anything?
```

or more formally

```
which individuals of the ontology are known
    not to have a follow relationship to any other individual
```

E.g. if your ontology states that

```
John does not follow Mary.
John does not follow himself.
Every individual in the ontology is either John or is Mary.
```

then `John` will be the answer to the above query.
You can also get a named class as the query answer if the asked restriction holds for a (named) group of individuals. In any case, the following must hold: if you asserted that the answer (or a member of it) *does* have a `follow`-relation to some individual then it would render the ontology inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

OWL does not have any means for querying the data.  SPARQL is used for that.  So the SPARQL query to find all class definitions that do not have the property :R would be:

```
SELECT ?cls
WHERE {
   ?cls a owl:Class .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {?cls :R ?o}
}
```